# JQuery animate stopped working after upgrading to 1.8.2

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-1.8

Pretty simple...  I upgraded JQuery from 1.4.1 to 1.8.2 and the following code no longer works:

```
            function ShowToast()
            {
                $("#toast").animate({ height: '350px' }, 300, 'swing');
            }
```

Any suggestions as to why this would have happened?

Comment: $("#toast")  is correctly finding the div I want to animate...

Comment: If you could add a jsfiddle to the post that would be awesome.

Comment: You sure it's not something else breaking, as that looks ok.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rv8Pc/ it seems working

Comment: Please add a demo, otherwise, there's nothing to do here.

Comment: you all were right, the function itself was not the problem

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this probably boiled down to poor design on my part.  I had display: none set for the div, and in JQuery 1.4.1, calling the animate() function seemed to overwrite that setting.  However 1.8.2 does not (which is probably better).

just needed to add

```
$("#toast").css('display', 'block');
```

to my function

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YGXAf/11/
there it is working

Comment: you're right, 1.4.1 switched it to the display:block automatically: http://jsfiddle.net/rv8Pc/2/